# How to implement this dependency ( react-native-pull-to-refresh) on the provided component, particularly the part with fetchPopularMovies?

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import type { Dispatch as ReduxDispatch } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPopularMovies } from '../../actions/PopularMovieActions';
import MovieCard from '../../components/movieCard/MovieCard';
type Props = {
  fetchPopularMovies: Function,
  popularMovies: Object,
  navigation: Object,
}
class ListOfPopularContainer extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPopularMovies();
  }
  render() {
    const { popularMovies, navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <StatusBar
          translucent
          backgroundColor="transparent"
          barStyle="light-content"
        />
        <FlatList
          data={popularMovies}
          keyExtractor={item => item.title}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <MovieCard navigation={navigation} card={item} />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  popularMovies: state.movies.popularMovies,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ReduxDispatch): Function => (
  bindActionCreators({ fetchPopularMovies }, dispatch)
);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListOfPopularContainer);
```

How to use it with the **this.props.fetchPopularMovies()**?
Is there some way to combine them, if you know, have any example or some experience with it please don't be shy to give some input on this problem.
The main thing I wont to do here is refreshing the screen when someone pulls it down.

Comment: Why don't just use 'refreshing' and 'onRefresh' on your FlatList?

Comment: I have to use react-native-pull-to-refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove funtion **_delay()** on both android and ios in **node_module/react-native-pull-to-refresh/PullToRefreshView**, then call funtion **_endLoading()** after this.props.fetchPopularMovies() success

```
_handleOnRefresh() { // remove delay
   this.props.onRefresh()
}

// your component 
import PTRView from 'react-native-pull-to-refresh'
...

class ListOfPopularContainer extends Component<Props> {

   refresh = () => {
      this.props.fetchPopularMovies().then({
         this.PTRView._endLoading()// call end loading
   }}

   render() {
      const { popularMovies, navigation } = this.props;
      return (
         <View>
           <StatusBar
             translucent
             backgroundColor="transparent"
             barStyle="light-content"
           />
           <PTRView
             style={{ backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF' }}
             onRefresh={this.refresh}
             ref={c => this.PTRView = c}
           >
             <FlatList
               data={popularMovies}
               keyExtractor={item => item.title}
               renderItem={({ item }) => (
                 <MovieCard navigation={navigation} card={item} />
           )}
             />
           </PTRView>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
```